# c#: Looking for data structure similar to Dictionary, that doesn't raise an error when indexing with a non-existing key

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-structures

I like using Dictionary, but checking every time if some key exists before indexing it is a nuisance. Is there any built-in data structure in c#, that would return null when a key doesn't exist, instead of raising an error?
If there is none, is there some custom class for that? I would like to avoid creating my own class and I'm not sure if this behavior is even possible.

Comment: `myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? value : defaultValue` in your case `myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? value : null`

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko, yes, but this is ugly, I just want to write myDict["some key"], which is much cleaner and not worry about it raising an error.